# Is there a newer version of Office for the MacOS anytime soon?

Tags: ms-office

I was wondering if Microsoft is planning to release Office 2012 anytime soon ? Shall I wait for it or purchase Office 2011 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlikely,

"traditionally" new Microsoft Office for Mac follow new releases of Microsoft Office for Windows:

- MS Office 2007 (Win) → [MS Office 2008 (Mac)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_for_Mac_2011) (released January 15, 2008)
- MS Office 2010 (Win) → [MS Office 2011 (Mac)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2008_for_Mac) (released October 26, 2010)

The currently developed version of Microsoft Office for Windows is [MS Office 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2013). So you can expect the next version for Mac to be MS Office 2014 which should start shipping anywhere between late 2013 and 2014.